# ListView can not move with "up" or "down" in remote control if I add key listener to listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I add a key listener to `ListView`, code is as follow:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
List<String> lists = new ArrayList<String>();
lists.add("item1");
lists.add("item2");
lists.add("item3");
lists.add("item4");
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        lists);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return true;  // here if I return true, the list view can not move focus
        //return false; // if I return false, the list view can move focus
    }
});
```

I want to know why is this?

Comment: any specific reason for the `OnKeyListener`.What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: in listview not use keylistener user onitemclick listener.

Comment: @Droidekas I want to show contextmenu when some item of listview is selected when I press `MENU`, so I add `OnKeyListener` to listview

Comment: @KrunalIndrodiya why? I need to operate with remote control, and I have rewrite the `OnItemClick` for some other function. Now, I want to show contextmenu when I press `MENU`

Comment: if i am not wrong that, context menu should open in onlongclick listener, for more info please check this tutorial http://www.mikeplate.com/2010/01/21/show-a-context-menu-for-long-clicks-in-an-android-listview/

Comment: yes, I know that, I want to also show it when press `MENU`

Comment: ok tell me the flow here,user clicks on an item and then that remains selected and then you press menu button.Am i correct?

Comment: @Droidekas，because I am in TV platform, so I do not need to click, just move focus to the item(in fact, the item is selected, not focused, because the listview get focused), then press MENU, the context menu will show.

Comment: AFAIK,on the TV sdk you dont need to specifically add `onKeyListener` for the movement.You could add an overall `onKeyListener` and then if it is `menu` button,you could get the focused item from the list and do the needful